# ListFragment selector selects all items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have this ListFragment, which I am calling in my Activity this way:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setTitle( getString(R.string.something) );
        
        if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
            final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            final Fragment f = CustomerListFragment.newInstance();
            ft.add( android.R.id.content, f, FRAG_TAG_CUSTOMER_LIST );
            ft.commit();
        }
        
    }
```

On my Fragment I have setted single choice:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

In my manifest I have setted it a style:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.CustomerListActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppList">
```

The theme is defined as follow:

```
<style name="Theme.AppList">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/AppListView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White">
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@color/selector_color</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
        <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/list_item</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and the colors:

```
<color name="list_item">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="selector_color">#ffba00</color>
```

But, whenever the app runs, it looks fine until I long press an item or try to drag. Then all the elements get selected and looks like this, instead of only selecting one element.

So the question is: How do I make the list to select only 1 element instead of all of them.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the solution to this was to implement a selector xml, where I added all the states of the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_selected"></item>  <!-- pressed -->    
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_selected"/>         <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item"/>       <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

the selector drawable states where 9 patch images.
then on the XML where I defined the row I setted the layout backgroud as the selector as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/space_screen_borders"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_screen_borders"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_selector" 
    > 
    ... your layout items 
</LinearLayout>
```

the manifest activity as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.CustomerListActivity" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppList">
```

and finally the theme as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.AppList">
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
   <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/AppListView</item>
</style>
<style name="AppListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView.White">
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">4dp</item>
    <!--item name="android:background">@color/</item-->
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/list_item</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and then the listview would show as intended with a white background for the elements and blue background for the activity and a 4dp transparent space between elements.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make the listSelector `@android:color/transparent` and set the individual row view's selector to `@color/selector_color`

Comment: maybe I'm doing this wrong, so I better ask this: how do I set the individual row view's selector??